# iOS: UITableView won't load cells when left anchor is view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, but will load if it is just view.leftAnchor

Tags: ios, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I have a view controller animating in from the left edge of screen, and this view controller has a `UITableView` subview.

On every device and orientation except for one (iPhone X in landscape), this  table view shows properly.

On the iPhone X in landscape, the table view is in the correct place but its cells do not populate until you scroll the tableView. Once you scroll, the table view is as if it had been there the whole time but with invisible cells.

This constraint causes the cells to not load:

```
[tableView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor].active = YES;
```

And when replacing this constraint with the following, the problem is solved as well:

```
[tableView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor].active = YES;
```

I've made the background of the UITableView red to show that it is correctly placed, but no rows are showing even though they load in the portrait orientation.

[image]

I've also tried leaving it as:

```
[tableView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor].active = YES;
```

but doing:

```
[tableView setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever];
```

which solves the problem for header cells:
[image: header cells look correct]

but not content cells:
[image: regular cells not indented]

This code causes the same issue:

```
[tableView setInsetsContentViewsToSafeArea:YES];
```

I am setting up my regular cells like this :

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if([reuseIdentifier isEqual: @"LayerCell"]) {
    _titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    _imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    _toggleView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    [_imgView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self addSubview:_imgView];
    [_imgView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.heightAnchor multiplier:0.8].active = YES;
    [_imgView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.heightAnchor multiplier:0.8].active = YES;
    [_imgView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.centerYAnchor].active = YES;
    [_imgView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.leftAnchor constant:8].active = YES;
    [_imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

    [self addSubview:_toggleView];
    [_toggleView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [_toggleView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_imgView.heightAnchor].active = YES;
    [_toggleView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_imgView.widthAnchor].active = YES;
    [_toggleView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_imgView.centerYAnchor].active = YES;
    [_toggleView.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.rightAnchor constant:-10].active = YES;
    [_toggleView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

    [self addSubview:_titleLabel];
    [_titleLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [_titleLabel.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:20].active = YES;
    [_titleLabel.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_imgView.centerYAnchor].active = YES;
    [_titleLabel.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_toggleView.leftAnchor constant:-10].active = YES;
    [_titleLabel.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_imgView.rightAnchor constant:10].active = YES;
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: Seems like you want `[tableView setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentAutomatic];` and `[tableView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor].active = YES;` What breaks when you do that?

Comment: regular cells do not get indented, as in the 3rd picture in my question.

Comment: How are you setting up your cells?

Comment: I programatically anchor the cell subviews to the cell itself, as shown above in my edit to the question.

Comment: You should add your cell's contents to your cell's `contentView`. For example `[self.contentView addSubview:_imgView];` You should also constrain it to your cell's `contentView` (e.g. `[_imgView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.heightAnchor multiplier:0.8].active = YES;`, `[_toggleView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.trailingAnchor constant:-10].active = YES;`, etc.) A cell's `contentView` will be inset to accommodate safe areas but a cell itself will not.

Comment: Thank you! that was the fix.